# What's the Unicode code point for '¿'?

Tags: unicode

[Google hasn't been a help.](http://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=unicode+for+%C2%BF&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

Comment: Silly, don't search ¿ search upside down question mark.

Comment: Why was this closed? As far as questions go, it can't get more real and specific than this one.

Comment: [Shapecatcher](http://shapecatcher.com) is a fairly new tool for similar questions. [It works](http://imgur.com/hCYAH) for the upside down question mark.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A quick search on Google for "unicode for upside down question mark" led me to a Wikipedia [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Question_mark), which stated that

> The inverted question mark (¿) corresponds to Unicode code-point 191 (U+00BF)

¿ɹoɟ buıʞooן ǝɹǝʍ noʎ ʇɐɥʍ ʇɐɥʇ sı

Answer (score 15):

If you want to obtain the Unicode value of a character you can use this simple Javascript :

```
javascript:alert("¿".charCodeAt(0))
```

This will alert the Unicode value of the character. If you want to use it in HTML, the synthax is & #191; (without space between & and #) where 191 is the Unicode number of your character.

Comment: ...and if you want the U+nnnn hex code unit, `'¿'.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)`.

Answer (score 2):

According to Ubuntu's *gucharmap*:

```
U+00BF INVERTED QUESTION MARK

General Character Properties

In Unicode since: 1.1
Unicode category: Punctuation, Other

Various Useful Representations

UTF-8: 0xC2 0xBF
UTF-16: 0x00BF

C octal escaped UTF-8: \302\277
XML decimal entity: &#191;

Annotations and Cross References

Alias names:
 • turned question mark

Notes:
 • Spanish

See also:
 • U+003F QUESTION MARK
 • U+2E2E REVERSED QUESTION MARK
```

Answer (score 2):

I use [this site](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/search.htm) as search tool for unicode characters. Here are the [search results](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/search.htm?q=%C2%BF&preview=entity) for `¿`. It has one result: [Unicode Character 'INVERTED QUESTION MARK' (U+00BF)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00bf/index.htm).

Useful site.

Answer (score 1):

Google is a help ALWAYS:

http://www.google.com/search?hl=pl&q=unicode+for+inverted+question+mark&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=

and:

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/bf/index.htm

answer: U+00BF

Answer (score 1):

If you know Java you can print it like this:

```
$ cat UnicodeTest.java  
public class UnicodeTest { 
    public static void main( String [] args )  { 
        System.out.println( ( int ) '¿' );
    }
}


$ javac -encoding UTF8 UnicodeTest.java  
$ java UnicodeTest
191
```

Answer **191**

Java's characters are unicode.

BTW, ¡That's not an upside down question mark! it is an "opening" question mark. It is just not everyone uses it, just like a '(' is not an upside parenthesis.

Comment: The Unicode standard calls it an 'INVERTED QUESTION MARK'

Answer (score 0):

[Unicode table](http://www.tamasoft.co.jp/en/general-info/unicode.html) might be helpful 00A01F.

Comment: It isn't `00a01f`; you add `1f` to `00a0` using hex arithmetic, giving `00bf`.

Comment: No problem :) (15 chars)